# Getting System.Web.Mvc.SelectListItem as options of DropDownList

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, asp.net-mvc

I have a `ViewBag.CategoryList` which contains `ViewBag.CategoryList = new SelectList(Category.GetCategories());`

My View:

```
@Html.LabelFor(model => model.Category, htmlAttributes: new { @class = "control-label col-md-2" })
@Html.DropDownListFor(model => model.Category, new SelectList(ViewBag.CategoryList), "Select Category", htmlAttributes: new {@class = "form-control"})
```

What I'm getting is `<option>System.Web.Mvc.SelectListItem</option>` instead of my strings. Debugger shows that the ViewBag does have a list of strings.

Edit:
Fixed it by replacing the view with:

```
@Html.DropDownListFor(model => model.Category, (IEnumerable)(ViewBag.CategoryList), "Select Category", htmlAttributes: new { @class = "form-control" })
@Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.Category, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
```

Answer (score 1):

actually give a select list instead of a string list from the controller.

```
ViewBag.CategoryList = Category.GetCategories().Select(r => new SelectListItem()
            {
                Value = r,
                Text = r
            })
```

```
@Html.DropDownListFor(model => model.Category, new SelectList(ViewBag.CategoryList, "Value", "Text"), "Select Category", htmlAttributes: new {@class = "form-control"})
```

Comment: sorry for not explaining properly. My code is as the following `ViewBag.CategoryList = new SelectList(Category.GetCategories());` `GetCategories` returns a List of strings.

Comment: I edited it based on what you said. Note that the value and text are the same, but you can fiddle with that if you want.

Answer (score 0):

try this

```
var list=Category.GetCategories();
ViewBag.CategoryList = list.Select(i => new SelectListItem
            {
                Value = i.Id.ToString(),
                Text = i.Name
            })
```

and view

```
@Html.DropDownListFor(model => model.Category, @ViewBag.CategoryList,"Select Category", htmlAttributes: new { @class = "form-control" })
```